# EntityFramework naming conventions for DDD ValueObjects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design, value-objects

I use Domain Driven Design Pattern in my project. I have some [ValueObjects](http://grabbagoft.blogspot.com/2007/06/generic-value-object-equality.html) like **PersianDate** that has a long type property. the name of ValueObject property in database be CreatedOn_PersianDate but I want its name be CreatedOn. I can change this property directly but how can i do it by **conventions**? (FixOValueObjectAttributeConvention)

```
public class PersianDate : ValueObject<PersianDate>
{
    public long Value {get; set;}
}

public class Account : Entity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public PersianDate CreatedOn {get; set;}
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FixObjectValueAttributeConvention());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ObjectValue<T>`?

Comment: @GertArnold this base class comes from Jimmy Bogard
http://grabbagoft.blogspot.com/2007/06/generic-value-object-equality.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably noticed that EF's naming convention for properties in complex types is

```
Property name + "_" + Property name in complex type
```

So by default, `CreatedOn` will be mapped as `CreatedOn_Value`. (As far as I can see, not the name `CreatedOn_PersianDate` that you mention, but it doesn't really matter for what follows).

You can create a custom code-first convention to modify this. I show you a convention that removes this "_Value" suffix for each property of type `long` (bigint):

```
class PersionDateNamingConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmProperty>
{
    public void Apply(EdmProperty property, DbModel model)
    {
        if (property.TypeName == "bigint" && property.Name.EndsWith("_Value"))
        {
            property.Name = property.Name.Replace("_Value", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can fine-tune the conditions when this convention is applied as needed.

You have to add this convention to the model builder (in `OnModelCreating`) to make it effective:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new PersionDateNamingConvention());
```

Comment: IStoreModelConvention doesn't work in Entity Framework 7 (EF Core 1.0)

Comment: So you use EF7? Would have been nice to know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using [DataAnnotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

> Column attribute can be applied to properties of a class. Default Code First convention creates a column name same as the property name. Column attribute overrides this default convention. EF Code-First will create a column with a specified name in Column attribute for a given property.

So your models would be:

```
public class Account : Entity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Column("CreatedOn")]
    public PersianDate CreatedOn {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: i want use conventions.